# How do I add parameters on Modelio, UML

Tags: uml, modelio

[image]

I can't really find how to add arguments on a Operation, how can I do it? The picture above is the program I use, Modelio...

How do I add arguments on Operation?

And how do I add a return value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all please find here the Modelio forum if you have any futher question (the reponses would be faster I guess ...).

Now concerning your issue, for creation Operation parameters or Operation return values you have to use the Operation contextual menu.

In order to show the Operation contextual menu, select your Operation **in the explorer**, then right click on it as show in my attachment and use "create element" > Parameter or Return Parameter.

[image]

Hoping it helps,

BR

Comment: Could you please tell me how do I change the parameter type?

Comment: Select your parameter and in the Element view use the 'Type' fields. More question ? Maybe post on modelio forum http://modelio.org

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it! I just didn't see the `Element` view!